# Ignore URL segments in 301 Redirect rule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Struggling with a 301 redirect rule to ignore additional URL segments.  Here is the goal:

Redirect URLs in this format: `example.com/product-category/category-parent/category-child/` to a new target URL.

Here is the rule in `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect 301 /product-category/category-parent/category-child/ https://newurl.com/
```

The redirecting is happening fine, except that the child segment of the URL is passed thru to the new URL so I end up with `newurl/category-child/` which is a 404.

EDIT:
Tried using `RedirectMatch` for the few specific nested category URLs with no luck:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /product-category/parent/child/ https://newurl.com/
```

Still produces `https://newurl.com/child` which is a 404.

Comment: Neither of the two directives you posted would result in the responses you are seeing!? The first (`Redirect`) rule would result in `https://newurl.com/something` only if you requested `/product-category/category-parent/category-child/something`. 301 (_permanent_) redirects are persistently cached by the browser, so it's possible you were seeing an erroneously cached redirect. Your second `RedirectMatch` rule certainly cannot produce the response you were seeing (if it was then your "answer" would also result in the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted out how to do what I needed.  Apache's `RedirectMatch` is what I needed with the proper regular expression.

```
RedirectMatch permanent "^/product-category/(.*)" "https://newurl.com/"
```

This will match any number of any character after the `/product-category/` segment and redirect to the new target URL, which is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You don't need the capturing subgroup in the regex, `^/product-category/` would suffice (and is more efficient). You are also missing the trailing slash after the hostname on the target URL.